# Hdmi sound not listed in output devices

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

i have ubuntu 18.04LTS, my hdmi video output works fine but the sound always comes from the laptop speakers. I also can't see any output device besides the speakers. I have tried many suggestions that i found on the web but nothing worked. I have the nvidia drivers installed, i have tried pulseaudio volume profiles, etc...
I have an hp omen i7 with a nvidia geforce gtx. Any suggestions to make the sound output through my tv instead of my laptop? Thanks in advance.